# MariaDB my.cnf optimization 8 Core 16GB Ram

Tags: mariadb, my.cnf

What would be the most optimized mariadb settings for my server below?

E5-2699 V4 CPU(8 Core)-
16GB DDR4 -
100GB NVME SSD

Current

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema=ON
slow_query_log = 1
query_cache_size = 32M

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 10G
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 10G

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
max_allowed_packet=256M
open_files_limit=40000
table_open_cache=40000

innodb_use_native_aio = 0
disable-log-bin = 1
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
max_connect_errors = 1000000
event_scheduler = off
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
character-set-server = utf8
default_storage_engine = InnoDB

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G # Use up to 70-80% of RAM
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
innodb_temp_data_file_path = ibtmp1:64M:autoextend:max:20G

# innodb_large_prefix=1
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
low_priority_updates = 1
concurrent_insert = 2
back_log = 512
thread_cache_size = 100
thread_stack = 192K
innodb_sort_buffer_size = 4M
join_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 4M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 2M
max_heap_table_size = 2G
tmp_table_size = 2G
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
innodb_io_capacity_max = 4000

sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
unix_socket=OFF
```

What I want is to be able to capture the most optimized settings for my server. Can you help me?

Comment: What version of MariaDB?

Comment: "Optimized" depends on workload, which is why these aren't just defaults.

Answer (score 1):

```
max_heap_table_size = 2G --> 160M
tmp_table_size = 2G --> 160M
query_cache_size = 32M --> 0
long_query_time = 1
table_open_cache=40000 --> 4000
utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
innodb_buffer_pool_size is mentioned twice; use 11G
```

The number of cores should not matter.  If you do hit high CPU, then let's look at indexes and query formulation (not settings).

Answer (score 0):

Try increase innodb_buffer_pool_size to 70% of RAM, it should be 16*0.7 = 11.2Go